# Keep disabled ion-item's background color in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, background-color

I try this:

```
  .ion-item:disabled {
    background-color:#ffffff !important;
  }
```

But it has no effect. I don't want it to have gray background when disabled, I try keep the original (white) color.

The code is like:

```
  <ion-list>
   <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items [disabled]="!item.enabled" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
    {{ item }}
   </button>  
  </ion-list>
```

So if `item.enabled` is false, the background gets gray but I need it white.

UPDATE: No need to add anything to CSS, the container's background color was gray, and perhaps the disabled items got transparent or something, but changing the container's color from gray to white resolved this issue.

Comment: Check what is rendered with the `ion-item`, you probably have the wrong selector. What does your template look like where you use `ion-item`?

Comment: This is the [basic list](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#lists).

Answer (score 2):

```
button.item[disabled]{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but still no change, the background remains grey.

Comment: Can you show me your (click)=itemSelected() function

Answer (score 2):

With changing the container's background color the issue was resolved. (Container where this list in.)
The container's default background color was grey.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like:

```
ion-item [disabled] {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Note that you are targetting `ion-item` as an element, **not a class**.

Here is the corresponding markup:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Normal input</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Normal Input"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Disabled input</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Disabled input" disabled></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[Here is a Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/36xkFNeqmakOlHGdmx8T?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry but this has no effect on iOS, nor on Android. The disabled list item's background is still grey.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the opacity which changes your background color, to retain background color, simply add opacity: 1 to any disabled element you want to retain background color. default opacity for any disabled element is 0.4.

> CSS style for [disabled]

```
  a[disabled], button[disabled], [ion-button][disabled] {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: .4;
  pointer-events: none;
  }
```